# Toggle phone sound, vibration and internet access On/Off using a CheckBoxPreference

Tags: android, audio, checkbox, sharedpreferences, vibration

How can I toggle the whole system sound, vibration, data connection and wifi using CheckBoxPreference in Android?
I want to have the possibility to disable these things while an activity is running in my app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.

In `res/xml/preferences.xml` add the CheckBoxPreferences:

```
    <CheckBoxPreference
        android:defaultValue="false"
        android:key="pref_disableSoundAndVibration"
        android:title="Disable sound and vibration" />
    <CheckBoxPreference
        android:defaultValue="false"
        android:key="pref_disableWifi"
        android:title="Disable Wi-Fi" />
```

In your MainActivity add two boolean members to store the audio and wifi checkbox state and one integer for the ringer state(Silent, Vibrate, Sound).

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    mDisableSoundAndVibration = mPref.getBoolean("pref_disableSoundAndVibration", false);
    AudioManager aManager=(AudioManager)getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE);
    mRingerMode = aManager.getRingerMode();

    mDisableWifi = mPref.getBoolean("pref_disableWifi", false);
    WifiManager wifiManager  = (WifiManager)this.getSystemService(WIFI_SERVICE);
    mWifiMode = wifiManager.isWifiEnabled();
    ...
    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        mDisableSoundAndVibration = savedInstanceState.getBoolean("disableSoundAndVibration");
        mDisableWifi = savedInstanceState.getBoolean("disableWifi");
...
}

public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String s) {
    ...
    mDisableSoundAndVibration = mPref.getBoolean("pref_disableSoundAndVibration", false);
    mDisableWifi = mPref.getBoolean("pref_disableWifi", false);
    ...
}
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    ...
    outState.putBoolean("disableSoundAndVibration", mDisableSoundAndVibration);
    outState.putInt("ringerMode", mRingerMode);
    outState.putBoolean("disableWifi", mDisableWifi);
    ....
}
```

If you want to temporary disable sound and wi-fi and retain the initial state:

```
    if (mDisableSoundAndVibration){
        AudioManager aManager=(AudioManager)getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE);
        aManager.setRingerMode(aManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT);
            }
    if (mDisableWifi){
        WifiManager wifiManager  = (WifiManager)this.getSystemService(this.WIFI_SERVICE);
        wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(false);
            }
```

And then to restore the initial values:

```
    if (mDisableSoundAndVibration){
        AudioManager aManager=(AudioManager)getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE);
        aManager.setRingerMode(mRingerMode);
    }
    if(mDisableWifi){
        WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager)this.getSystemService(WIFI_SERVICE);
        wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(mWifiMode);
    }
```